# Duplicated symbols with static library(.a) and dynamic library (.dylib)

Tags: ios, paypal

In my iOS project, the libraries `libbaidumapapi.a` and `libPayPalMPL.a` are being used.

The project can be correctly built  but it signals an exception at runtime.

While debugging the problem, I found that its  cause is because library `libPayPalMPL.a` invokes the `XMLFreeDoc` function inside library `libbaidumapapi.a`, but it should be invoking the XMLFreeDoc function inside `xml2` dynamic library.

I don't have source codes of both libraries.  When I check the `libbaidumapapi.a`, I found out that it is archived with `minixml.o` and `deflate.o` with XMLFreeDoc and deflate that may conflict with `libPayPalMPL.a`.

`libPayPalMPL.a` library that depends on two dynamic libraries: `xml2` and `zlib`.

I can I fix this crash issue?  I already use `force_load` before `libbaidumapapi.a`.

The following is the link command, just in case it is needed.

```
Ld /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/travel-aaytjupqtzenxvaepekwcapqqzpv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/travel.app/travel normal i386
cd /Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/itravel-aaytjupqtzenxvaepekwcapqqzpv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp/libs/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp/libs/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp/libs/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp/libs -L/Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp/libWeiboSDK -L/Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp/Library -F/Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/travel-aaytjupqtzenxvaepekwcapqqzpv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/travel-aaytjupqtzenxvaepekwcapqqzpv/Build/Intermediates/travel.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/travel.build/Objects-normal/i386/travel.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -force_load /Users/tony/Documents/temp/mapapp/libs/Release-iphonesimulator/libbaidumapapi.a -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -lz -lxml2 -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -lc++ -lopts -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPayPalMPL -lWeiboSDK -o /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/travel-aaytjupqtzenxvaepekwcapqqzpv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/travel.app/travel*
```

Answer (score 0):

MPL has been deprecated. Instead, it's recommended that you use the iOS SDK: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Comment: Seems PayPal-iOS-SDK is for US only.  I'm developing an app for a customer in China. I see that PayPal-iOS-SDK also depends on libxml2.dylib.  I believe the result is the same.  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/